# UTL_HTTP http request

Tags: oracle11g

My question is , when i make a web request using oracle 11g UTL_HTTP package , in my parameter set i send 3parameters fro the restful web service , but in web service for one param recive only part of data. in data param recive only up to EW185 only what is the error in my code?

my code,

```
           pdata:=null;

    pdata:='<?xml version="1.0"?><XML>
    <PARTS>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>AD3U1600W4G11-B</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>RAM ADATA DDR3 4GB</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>E209329</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>2</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>SATA Cables(Lian Feng)</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>K100</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Key Board</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>M100</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Mouse</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>EWCS4X6</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Packaging Stickers</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>EWCBMT</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Carton Boxes MT</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>EW185</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>MONITOR  EZY 18.5&quot;</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>i5-3470</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Processor Intel i5</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>H61H2-M</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Mother board (ECS)</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>DT01ACA100</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>HDD TOSHIBA 1TB</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>DESK-ProSE</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>DESKTOP Product Serial Label</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>PN502</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>Casing with power supply</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>FQC-05646</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>WINDOWS 8 PRO LICENSES</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>Q101</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>COOLING FAN(Q101)</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>YHS-100M</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>2</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>CABLE TIE</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>EWRL25X60</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>E-WIS RATING LABEL</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>HD5450</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>VGA Cards 1GB</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    <PART>
    <PART_NO>SH-224</PART_NO>
    <PART_QTY>1</PART_QTY>
    <PART_NAME>ODD DVD, SATA</PART_NAME>
    </PART>
    </PARTS>
    <CONFIG_NO>HT-39</CONFIG_NO><MODEL_NO>EWIS PRO 2400</MODEL_NO><MODEL_NAME>EWIS PRO 2400 MT PC</MODEL_NAME></XML>';
    l_param_list := 'U=admin@admin.com&P=password&data='||pdata; 


    l_param_list:=replace(l_param_list,';','');


    l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('loclahost/app/admin/index.php /api/serial/put_config' , 'POST' , 'HTTP/1.1');



    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_param_list));

    UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);


    l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

    UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

    UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The error is in the XML Code , there is a OS conversion for special character in ITEM No , here its for double quotes ". when submitting this request XML part truncate where this conversion is lies. To prevent this I have to remove special characters in the XML

```
 under pdata XML string <PART_NAME>MONITOR  EZY 18.5&quot;</PART_NAME> this line cause    
 error
```